# How can I make this class comparable in terms of count?

Tags: python, list, sorting, oop, comparable

I have class called `WordCount` with two properties - the word itself and its frequency/count. I'm going through a book line by line and adding each `WordCount` instance to a list.

```
class WordCount:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.count = 1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.word == other.word
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.word < other.word
```

I'm trying to set this up in a way where the `WordCount`s are ordered in terms of their count and not the word itself (as it is currently). However, when I change the code to this:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.count == other.count:
            return self.word == other.word
        
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.count < other.count
```

It doesn't give me the order I'm looking for. I've been playing around with other variations as well but none of them are giving me the correct order. Additionally, in the case where the count is the same, I want the program to use the word to order the objects.

Comment: What is the input & expected output ?

Comment: Are you gong to use the built-in sorts - sorted, list.sort?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need objects to be generally comparable to sort them. Unlike Java and C which use comparators for ordering, python uses sort keys, which are more efficient because you only need to compute the key once, and you can use different keys as you see fit.

For example:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: (x.count, x.word))
```

Or slightly more efficiently, using the standard library:

```
from operator import attrgetter

mylist.sort(key=attrgetter('count', 'word'))
```

The objects returned by the key function do have to be comparable. `tuple`s are compared lexicographically, so are a popular choice for keys when you need to compare attributes in a hierarchy.

Comment: Is there a simple way to use this approach to also account for this part of OP's question? "Additionally, in the case where the count is the same, I want the program to use the word to order the objects."

Comment: @kingkupps. Updated. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare by more than one attribute, you need to account for more than one attribute in your `__lt__` implementation. Something like:

```
class WordCount(object):

    def __init__(self, word, count=1):
        self.word = word
        self.count = count

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.count < other.count:
            return True
        return self.word < other.word

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}: {}'.format(self.word, self.count)


counts = [
    WordCount('hat', 3),
    WordCount('cat', 2),
    WordCount('dog', 5),
    WordCount('stuff', 5),
    WordCount('word', 1),
]
print(*sorted(counts), sep='\n')
```

Which prints:

```
word: 1
cat: 2
dog: 5
hat: 3
stuff: 5
```